# How to clone physical system into a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I have a full system installed on my PC. (Arch Linux on a laptop)

I need to test, edit, tweak this system (bootloader too) in a safe way because it is my workstation.

Is there a way to easily** clone/replicate the current system into a VM (I usually use `gnome-boxes` but software used doesn't matter)

---

** *easy means: time needed to **convert** physical installed into virtual is **less** than **install** a VM from scratch*

---

**EDIT**:
As I guess and @Terence state, I need to copy the entire disk somewhere. The source disk is a 256GB SSD but I do not have any other medium **large enough** in which clone it entirely.

Is there a way to clone **only** the **mandatory partitions** (in my case: boot/EFI and root) roughly 50GB and the **bootloader**, while leaving behind others (home and swap) for the remaining 200GB?

In this case I will clone them in my *$HOME* directly!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to dump the disk to a file on external drive (for write speed and space).

```
# /dev/sda is assumed your laptop drive
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M of=/path/to/external_drive_mounted/laptop_dump.raw
```

Then create a disk for `virtualbox`:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /path/to/file.vmdk \
    -rawdisk /path/to/external_drive_mounted/laptop_dump.raw
```

This disk only points to the raw dump.

You can now create a virtual machine with this disk and play around.

Answer (score 0):

Boot live Linux...

Run GParted, shrink your Ext4 system. Create a new partition for the dump.

---

And then, here's an example as root:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | bzip2 > /some/path/sda-dd.bz2
```

This could give you some advantage in the means of additional space.

Comment: This is a great solution for backupping. What I mean is for cloning the system